# How does an encrypted wallet persist used keys from "getnewaddress" and the keypool after a restart?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, private-key, encryption, keypool

I'm reading [this wiki on wallet encryption](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_encryption)  and am confused on how I can call [getnewaddress as described here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4095/1878) and where that is being tracked after a restart of bitcoind.

> When a wallet is encrypted, the passphrase is required to top up the
>   keypool, thus, if the passphrase is rarely entered, it is possible
>   that keypool might run out. In this case, the default key will be used
>   as the target for payouts for mining, and calls to getnewaddress and
>   getaccount address will return an error. In order to prevent such
>   cases, the keypool is automatically refilled when walletpassphrase is
>   called with a correct passphrase and when topupkeypool is called
>   (while the wallet is unlocked). Note that the keypool continues to be
>   topped up on various occasions when a new key from pool is used and
>   the wallet is unlocked (or unencrypted).
>
> When wallet passphrase
>   enrcyption becomes enabled, any unused keys from the keypool are
>   flushed (marked as used) and new keys protected with encyption are
>   added. For this reason, make a new backup of your wallet so that you
>   will be able to recover the keys from the new key pool should access
>   to your backups be necessary.

Comment: The wallet.dat holds all private keys.  The "key pool" is simply a queue for those keys already in the wallet.dat that haven't been issued yet through "getnewaddress" or chosen for use as change in a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call it an infinite number of times. In fact, with default settings, the 101st call will fail.

While the private keys that control the bitcoins are encrypted, the addresses corresponding to those keys are not.

Comment: Fascinating... do you know where it's actually stored?

Comment: Somewhere in wallet.dat. Beyond that, I couldn't tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Getnewaddress simply marks a private key in the wallet.dat as being used (or, to be more specific, removes that address from the key pool) and returns that address in the response.

So the private key already exists in wallet.dat prior to the getnewaddress call.